# Is there a way to read frames from stream and parallely save it as video?

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a NN which detects people on video and I have an IP-cam, from which I'm getting video.
What I'm doing right now:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(source)
width = cap.get(3)
height = cap.get(4)
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
start = True
while True:
    ret,img = cap.read()
    if *NN part*:
        if start:
            out = cv2.VideoWriter(file, fourcc, 20.0, (width, height), True)
            start = False
        out.write(img)
        last_point = time.perf_counter()
    else:
        if time.perf_counter() - last_point < 5:
            out.write(img)
        else:
            out.release()
```

So I'm writing video with person + 5 seconds after it and then again.
It works, but it's eating my time.

I decided to use multiprocessing to read/save parallely.
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import argparse
import sys
from ksnn.api import KSNN
from ksnn.types import *
import cv2 as cv
import time
from pathlib import Path
import json
from numba import njit
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import perf_counter

<...>

def save_video(q):
    while True:
        flag, data = q.get()
        if flag==0:                                             # Create new video-file
            frame, size, path, n, fps = data
            fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
            file = "{}vid_{}.avi".format(path, n)
            out = cv.VideoWriter(file, fourcc, fps, size, True)
            image = cv.resize(frame, size)
            out.write(image)
        elif flag==1:                                           # Add frame
            frame, size = data
            image = cv.resize(frame, size)
            out.write(image)
        elif flag==2:                                           # Stop and release
            file = "{}vid_{}.avi".format(path, n)
            out.release()
            print("Done. Video was saved in {}".format(file))
            break
        else:
            pass

def main():
    if is_video_file or is_url or webcam:
        cap = cv.VideoCapture(source)
        mp.set_start_method('spawn')
        flag1 = flag2 = True
        n = 0
        q = mp.Queue()
        while(1):
            start = time.perf_counter()
            ret,img = cap.read()
            if flag1:
                q.put([-1, None])
                p = mp.Process(target=save_video, args=[q,])
                p.start()
                flag1 = False

            boxes, scores, classes = *NN part*

            if boxes is not None:
                if flag2:
                    q.put([0, img, size, path, n, FPS])
                    flag2 = False
                else:
                    q.put([1, img, size])
                lost_object = perf_counter()
            elif boxes is None and not flag2:
                if perf_counter() - lost_object < 5:
                    q.put([1, img, size])
                else:
                    q.put([2, path, n])
                    flag1 = flag2 = True
                    n+=1

            end = time.perf_counter()
            print('1 frame per: {}s'.format(end - start))
        cap.release()
```

(With Queue I'm giving function frames and different params)

But when I tried it, the program died:

> [Sat Jan 27 21:10:22 2024] Killed process 201971 (python3) total-vm:4786480kB, anon-rss:2889920kB, file-rss:88kB, shmem-rss:16kB

Can Anybody help out here?

Comment: can you turn that into a [mre]?

Comment: Actually it is an example, I just erased few functions, which are from my NN.

Comment: I am trying to make it work with `ThreadPoolExecutor`, I am getting some really weird results though, have you tried a similar approach so far? @RodionShkokov

Comment: @TinoD Yep, I've already moved to multithreading, but I got stuck here.

Comment: @RodionShkokov the biggest problem is that video writer and video capture are both not picklable, and hence it is not straight forward how this can be done. I could be wrong though, i've done some opencv stuff and some parallel computing stuff, but never something like this...

Comment: nobody should ever want to "pickle" a videowriter or videocapture object. why do you discuss that?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I was trying to figure out good args to pass the parallel functions. Defining inside the function does not work ofc, so I defined them in main and I was trying to pass them as a reader and writer, also does not work.

Comment: creating instances inside of threads/tasks *should* work. if it doesn't, there's another issue. -- multiprocessing should not be used for the hell of it. often it causes more issues, *such as* thinking you can just move instances between processes, which is not possible for such complex instances. multiprocessing MUST NOT BE the first suggestion. or the second. you need to understand how multiprocessing works internally. that understanding is crucial.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for the hints, I'll try what you suggested and see if it works

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz Actually I made it with mp, but it works not that good, I just made the infinite loop in function (not wise decision)
Decided moving to multithreading and got stuck here
I managed to push frames into two threads, but it's little bit slow + I'm creating threads in the loop and I dont know how to fix it

Comment: `flag, data = q.get()` cannot be correct if you are ever putting to the queue a list of more than two elements. For that you need `flag, *data = q.get()` so that `flag` is set to  the first element and `data` becomes a list of the remaining elements.